# Eclipse setup automation

Tags: java, eclipse, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omVsP.png)

due to constrain, I need to setup eclipse and other tools(Maven,Jboss,..etc) daily by moving from remote folder to C dive kind, to achieve this I use .bat file. But still i would need to do some manual work to updated Maven user settings and to add installed JDK kind. Is there way that this could also be automated ?

Comment: Anything can be automated. Can you more specific with what needs to be automated? JDK, for example, can be [installed silently](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#jdk-silent-installation). But it seems like you are looking for more than just that.

Comment: At present,  after opening eclipse work bench. I edit maven user setting and add JDK to Java – Installed JRE’s. 
Can that be automated ?